# How to use sstableloader from a node not in Cassandra Cluster ring

Tags: cassandra

we are using apache-cassandra 1.1.9 version on Production Cassandra Cluster on linux.I want to upload some data using sstableloader.
I was able to generate sstables for a small data and then tried to upload these sstables into Cassandra Cluster using sstableloader from another machine(which is in same network but not in cassandra cluster ring) but get below error

"Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:"

I do not understand why this error is coming.
This machine , where i am running sstableloader, has same cassandra installation.I copied the cassandra.yaml from production cassandra into my host machine's apache-cassandra/conf folder.

My sstables are in below directory structure:-
/path/to/keyspace dir/Keyspace/*.db

SStable command I am running is below

./sstableloader -d  -i , /home/Data/Keyspace/
Could not retrieve endpoint ranges:

Please advise , if i am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.
The sstableloader command needs to be executed from the directory containing the Keyspace subdirectory.
For e.g 
if /home/Data is the directory structure, under which there is sub directories keyspace/ColumnFamily/
then execute command like below from /home/Data/ directory.

~/apache-cassandra/bin/sstableloader -d  /keyspace/ColumnFamily

Comment: After running the above command whether we need to run any other node tool command like repair or clean? And also if I am having SSTable where I am trying to inject those using your above command in to the cassandra cluster of 10 node with replica of 3, Will it load all the data in to entire cluster. Which means whether the appropriate data  will move to corresponding node? Because I am running your command only in one node So I am little confused will the data move to corresponding node?

Comment: You should NOT necessarily need to run nodetool repair/clean command , Also it will be time consuming process. Unless you are seeing some issues in your Cluster, you should be fine. To answer second question - It will load data to replicas in your cluster , if you have the replication set at keyspace level. From what i know, Cassandra will take care of replicating data, if you load data on any specific node.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For second question I got partial answer for my question (For replicas, I got clear understanding from your comment). I asked about partition too, for example, the SSTable contains 100 row with partition key from 1 to 100, while running SSTableLoader will the 100 partition will get splitted over the cluster? Which means I created SSTable with MurMurPartitioner of 100 rows, after running the SSTableloader command will the row 1 moves to corresponding node A and row 2 will moves to node B and so on..?

Comment: The reason for my above question is, Since I am running the SSTableLoader command in one node with single IP address with command of -d (But actually I am having 25 nodes), So I am little bit confused whether the data that are responsible for the node where I am running only will be moved. But my assumption is, my command has one IP address but it will get all the peer information from the single node and it will move the data to concern node. Whether my assumption is correct?

Comment: I believe based on Partitioning configured in your Cluster, Cassandra should automatically take care of distributing the data across several nodes. You can give it a shot and monitor the Cluster using tools like OpsCenter to see, if data is getting distributed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but I ran into the "Could not retrieve endpoint ranges" error recently with a different root cause.

In our case, data was being exported from a production system, and loaded to a new development instance.  The development instance had been incorrectly set up so the sstables were generated using dse 4.7, and the sstableloader being run was dse 4.6.

Note that it is possible to ingest tables from 4.6  into dse 4.7 for debugging, etc, but that it is necessary to run nodetool upgradesstables first. That isn't what was going on here.